# Knockout is not defined? Did require js load anything?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So Consider the following:

```
addExternalLibrary: function(name, url) {
    _externalLibraries[name] = url;
    _librariesToLoad.push(name);
},

setUpRequireJS: function() {
  define('jquery', [], function() {
    return jQuery;
  });

  requirejs.config({
    paths: _externalLibraries,
    waitSeconds: 5
  });
},

load: function(options) {
  this.addExternalLibrary('jqueryUri', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min');
  this.addExternalLibrary('jqueryCookies', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min');
  this.addExternalLibrary('lodash', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.8.2/lodash');
  this.addExternalLibrary('knockout', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min');
  this.addExternalLibrary('knockoutValidation', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.min');

  this.setUpRequireJS();

  require(_librariesToLoad, function(){
    console.log(ko);
  });
},
```

Notice the `console.log(ko)` ?? Well apparently, `ko` is not defined, not even `window.ko` There are no errors in console, in regards to `requirejs` accept for: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined`

**So question**: Why is nothing loaded? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.ko` is correctly undefined because you are loading Knockout with RequireJs and in this case Knockout detects this and does not attach itself to the global object.

`console.log(ko)` is undefined because in your module definition function you haven't specified an `ko` argument.

If you want to access the dependencies in your module you need to define for each dependency an argument in the correct order.

So in your case the order is declared with your `_librariesToLoad` so `ko` should be the 4th one:

```
require(_librariesToLoad, function(jqueryUri, jqueryCookies, lodash, ko){
    console.log(ko);
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zhwcnev/).